# How to run Junit Test (Java) from VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, maven-3, junit5, vscode-debugger

I have an Eclipse Maven project that uses selenium and Junit to run some tests. 
It currently works fine when I run it as Junit Test.

I want to try out the ide from visual studio code but I can't get it to work. I am getting the following message:

> ConfigError: The project 'CopaSelfWebCheckIn' is not a valid java project.

[image]

I know there is no main folder. I rather run it from where it is right now.

Can someone explain me how to set this up. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is very old, but did you ensure you have all the Java extension packs and other requirements installed?

Comment: I did, I'm not an expert but I turned out it is actually hard to get the compiler configurations all right for this kind of java projects were there is not necessarily a main class. Eclipse and intellij just work way better for java projects.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have all the required `java` extension installed on your `VS-Code`

Mainly

1. `Test Runner for Java`
2. `Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat`
3. `Maven for Java` (if you have any dependencies)
4. `Debugger for Java`
5. `Project Manager for Java`

All these extensions are packed with a single extension [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack)

if you have installed proper dependencies and extensions your vscode will look similar to the below picture

[image: Vscode Java Testing View]